# How to generate a wordlist of alphabets using javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays

Hi Everyone I am New Here Basically i want to generate a array with the help of nodejs means i want to generate an array which keeps on generating alphabets like this

`array = ["A","B","C"..."Z","AA","BB",..."ZZ","AAA","BBB",..."ZZZ"]`

After googling i came across this one

```
function columnToLetter(column)
{
  var temp, letter = '';
  while (column > 0)
  {
    temp = (column - 1) % 26;
    letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;
    column = (column - temp - 1) / 26;
  }
  return letter;
}
```

But can't understand it still new to the language

Comment: Which part? `letter = String.fromCharCode(temp + 65) + letter;` decodes your char to string , where 65 represents "A" (see ASCII table or Unicode) ,"B" (66), "C" (67) etc. are following. Also, if you append the results of this function , it will not produce your array (e.g. after "AA" it will give you "AB" and not "BB")

Answer (score 0):

I think my method can meet your requirements

```js
function columnToLetter(column) {
    var letter = [],
        newLetter = [],
        merchant = Math.floor(column / 26),
        remainder = column % 26;
    if (merchant === 0) {
        for (let i = 0; i < remainder; i++) {
            newLetter.push(String.fromCharCode(i + 65));
        }
        return newLetter;
    } else if (merchant > 0) {
        for (let j = 0; j < 26; j++) {
            let str = String.fromCharCode(j + 65);
            letter.push(str)
        }
        for (let i = 1; i <= merchant; i++) {
            newLetter.push(...letter);
            letter = letter.map(item => item + item.split('')[0])
        }
        newLetter.push(...letter.slice(0, remainder));
        return newLetter;
    }
}

console.log(columnToLetter(28));
```